# how to protect location.href from cross site scripting in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-site, location-href, fortify

Here in my javascript function im using location.href as follows 
  `location.href = "../Floder1/result.jsp";` it is working fine but when i used fortify tool it is showing Cross-site Scripting `which can result in the browser executing malicious code.`  how to protect this from cross site scripting. Thank you very much,your answer will be very much appreciated.

Comment: where does the string that you are setting location.href come from?

Comment: Assigning value to location.href is wrong way?if so guide me please.

Comment: @Gabs00 ,flag does not do anything ,just for identification/validation i kept flag

Comment: @kinakuta,String come from cookies i think.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what exactly you are trying to achieve? The issue, and why you chose this solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078332/is-it-secure-to-use-window-location-href-directly-without-validation ,i referred this link 2nd answer but i dont know how to implement for my current requirement.

Comment: @Gabs00,now check my question,i have edited.Just im assigning value to location.href.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work only in firefox since Proxy isn't implemented in all browsers

What you can do is to replace the original `location` object with a proxied one where you add some logic to your proxy to check for allowed value for location. this will not protect against the direct modification of the original object (`location`) but if you use only the proxied object in your code you should be fine.

```
// suppose we are in example.com
let validator = {
   set: function(obj, prop, val) {
     if (prop === 'href') {
       if(typeof val != 'string'){
         throw new TypeError('href must be string.');
       }
       if (!val.startsWith("https://example.com/")) {
         throw new Error('XSS');
       }
     }
    obj[prop] = val;
    return true;
   },
   get: function(obj, prop){
    return prop in obj?
        obj[prop] :
        null;
   }
};
let proxiedLocation = new Proxy(location, validator);
console.log(proxiedLocation.href);// work same as location.href
proxiedLocation.href = "https://example.com/page1";// work fine
proxiedLocation.href = "https://example.net/page1";// cause exception
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Cross-site Scripting](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) occurs when the user can put data in the webpage or get session data for example.

**HOW PROTECT**

You **never allow** inject code in your webpage. So, if you have a form, check it in the server and parse it before print in your page.

You shouldn't allow that the page content is changed by the `href`. You always `escape` the data before!.

Read this answer about `location.href`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089350/2389232

**SAMPLE**:

You have a iframe what changes with a GET variable:

```
sample.tld/index.jsp?iframe=none.jsp
```

I can inject a `script` to your iframe so you should protect it with escape characters:

```
// Escape the characters in the server and send it to the client.
// So the variable GET iframe will be valid
```

Comment: ,how should i write condition for my current situation(question) to protect

Comment: snake,I'm not using any iframe in my code just i have this peace of code in my js function location.href = "../Floder1/result.jsp";

Comment: Which is the problem? These `location.href` redirect to another page. It is not a vulnerability. If **fortify tool** says that these line is a XSS vulnerability it is wrong. [Read this explain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24089350/2389232).

Comment: If it solves your problem mark it please :). Otherwise say me what you want to do. Regards!