# Preventing cross site scripting for window.location.href

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xss

I am using window.location.href to route the page to an external link:

```
<Route exact path={rootUrl} component={() => { window.location.href =`https://${window.location.hostname}/www/testurl?google=true`; return null; }} />
```

But this code is throwing  Cross-Site Scripting issue during FOD scan. Is there a cleaner way to do this ? Or is there a fix for it ?

Thanks for the help.

I referred this similar question but it didn't help:
[how to protect location.href from cross site scripting in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440918/how-to-protect-location-href-from-cross-site-scripting-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a component and use react router elements.

```
<Route
  path="/your-path"
  component={ Redirect }
  loc="https://your-link"
  />
```

this seems cleaner compared to what you have .
Also check this link for better understanding , i was able to research more on router links and found this on this platform.
[React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link)

if this helps you please mark it. Thank you